# Did the Buddha ever turn away certain people from his teachings?

Tags: buddha, teaching

I'm specifically remembering a sutra where the Buddha turned away some youngsters because he said they weren't ready, or didn't have the proper attitude. I may be remembering completely incorrectly and getting this confused with something else, but it's in my memory nonetheless and wonder if it's at all accurate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Buddha often didn't answer questions or attempt to teach others. [SN 44.10](https://suttacentral.net/sn44.10/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=true) is a well-known example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you remember, but similar:

Uposatha Sutta - One uposatha night, during the first watch, Ananda approaches the Buddha and asks him to recite the Patimokkha. Three times he asks, but the Buddha remains silent, and at last says that the assembly is impure. Mahamoggallana, who is present, looks round, and seeing there a monk given up to wicked ways, asks him to leave. On his refusing to do so, Moggallana takes him by the hand and leads him away. Thereupon the Buddha proceeds to explain how, just as the sea is full of eight kinds of marvels, so is the Dhamma. A.iv.204ff.

https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/uposatha-sutta

Answer (score 1):

In [SN 42.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn42.2/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=true&script=latin) and [SN 42.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn42.3/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=true&script=latin), an actor and a warrior ask the Buddha whether their professions would lead them to heaven based on their assumption of the positive contribution of their professions.

The Buddha tried to turn them away three times. When they were insistent, he proceeded to answer the question in the way that disappointed them.

Answer (score -1):

Buddha never turned away anyone who had the intention of understanding the Dhamma. Whether rich or poor , wise or layperson , king or a fisherman, saint or thief etc . No one was turned away. Some foolish people failed to understand what he said and Buddha can’t be blamed for that. Some people were against Buddha and there was no need to teach as such. Angoolimal was a dacoit and he converted to Buddha Dhamma by the blessings of Buddha.

In my opinion Buddha Dhamma is a great gift to give to anyone who is serious about understanding reality.